# Pagerjs not updating withOnShow after first visit

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, pagerjs

I'm using Pager.js and withOnShow to dynamicly fetch the correct data with a wildcard.
It works the first time you visit the page but if you navigate to a new id, the correct viewModel is returned but the bindings are not updated.

Html:

```
<div data-bind="page: {id: 'start'}">
    <a href=""  data-bind="page-href: '/11'">id 11</a>
    <a href=""  data-bind="page-href: '/12'">id 12</a>
</div>
<div data-bind="page: {id: '?', withOnShow: showView}">
    <h1 data-bind="text:id"></h1>
    <a href=""  data-bind="page-href: '/11'">id 11</a>
    <a href=""  data-bind="page-href: '/12'">id 12</a>
</div>
```

JS

```
vm = ko.mapping.fromJS({test: 1});
vm.showView = function(callback, page) {
    console.log(page.currentId);
    vm = ko.mapping.fromJS({id: page.currentId});
    callback(vm);
};
pager.useHTML5history = true;
pager.Href5.history = History;
pager.extendWithPage(vm);
ko.applyBindings(vm);
pager.startHistoryJs();
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xU4Uu/

Try navigating to one of the links and then use the new links to navigate to the other id. Console logs show the correct id returned but the h1 is not updated.

Am I using this wrong or is this a bug in pager.js? I'm in the middle of a project and I really need to get this to work. Has anyone solved this some how?

Comment: Wish I could help but not entirely sure what Pager.js does.  +1 to hopefully help someone else find your question.

Comment: It might be a pager.js bug... because if you change the KO version to 2.2.1 it works: http://jsfiddle.net/j8BTC/. By the way there is newer version of pager.js 1.0.1: https://github.com/finnsson/pagerjs#101 where they claim they've fixed this incompatibility problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code recreates viewmodel every time `.showView` is called. You should not recreate viewmodel but only update its properties.

Change:

```
vm = ko.mapping.fromJS({id: page.currentId});
```

to:

```
ko.mapping.fromJS({id: page.currentId}, vm);
```

Using `ko.mapping.fromJS` with VM as second parameter will update VM members with new values (passed with the first parameter respectively).

Corrected fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xU4Uu/1/

Comment: Thanks, seems pretty obvious now but none of the examples show it in action. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this is the answer. It's possible to use an independent (that is, not attached to $root) context; try <!-- ko with: {foo: 'bar'} -->. That one generates it dynamically in pagerjs shouldn't matter.